# How to keep cheked items checked when searching another one in ion-searchbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ionic-framework

What I want to achieve is to keep the checked items checked when searching another one in ion-searchbar. I managed to keep the checked items but the icon with check doesn't remain checked. What I want is that after I search to keep all the foods list and the ones checked to look liked checked and not to lose state.

This is how it looks:

[image: When I first check them]
[image: Search food]
[image: Search food checked]
[image: When I clear the search it remains the one checked but not with the icon checked]

This is my HTML:

```
<ion-header class="ion-padding ion-no-border">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title [hidden]="showSearch">Select Foods</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button [hidden]="showSearch" (click)="onCloseModal()">
        Close
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button [hidden]="!showSearch" (click)="showSearch = !showSearch">
        Close
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button (click)="showSearch = !showSearch">
        <ion-icon
          name="search-outline"
          slot="icon-only"
          [hidden]="showSearch"
        ></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-searchbar
      [hidden]="!showSearch"
      (ionChange)="onSearchFood($event)"
      class="items-searchbar"
      animated
      placeholder="Search Food"
    ></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let food of foods">
    <ion-item (ionChange)="onCheckbox($event)">
      <ion-label>{{ food.name }}</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox slot="end" value="{{ food.name }}"> </ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <h5 *ngIf="foods.length === 0">
    Oups, no food found.
  </h5>
</ion-content>
```

This is my TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ModalController } from "@ionic/angular";

@Component({
  selector: "app-search-modal",
  templateUrl: "./search-modal.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./search-modal.component.scss"],
})
export class SearchModalComponent implements OnInit {
  showSearch = false;
  searchQuery = "";
  foods = [
    { name: "Apple" },
    { name: "Cucumber" },
    { name: "Pineapple" },
    { name: "Sugar" },
    { name: "Nuts" },
  ];

  allFoods: Array<{ name: string }> = [];

  tickedFoods: Array<{ name: string }> = [];

  constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController) {
    this.allFoods = this.foods;
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  onCloseModal() {
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
  }

  onSearchIntolerance(event) {
    this.foods = this.allFoods;
    this.searchQuery = event.detail.value;
    if (this.searchQuery && this.searchQuery.trim() !== "") {
      this.foods = this.foods.filter((term) => {
        return (
          term.name
            .toLowerCase()
            .indexOf(this.searchQuery.trim().toLowerCase()) > -1
        );
      });
    } else if (this.searchQuery === "") {
      this.foods = this.tickedFoods;
    }
  }

  onCheckbox(event) {
    if (event.detail.checked === true) {
      let tickedFoods = event.detail.value;
      this.tickedFoods.push({ name: tickedFoods });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to keep the checked items available, you can use the `checked` feature of `ion-checkbox` and create a function to check if the food is present in the `tickedFoods` array.

```
onSearchIntolerance(event) {
    this.intolerances = this.allIntolerances;
    this.searchQuery = event.detail.value;
    if (this.searchQuery && this.searchQuery.trim() !== "") {
      this.intolerances = this.intolerances.filter(term => {
        return (
          term.name
            .toLowerCase()
            .indexOf(this.searchQuery.trim().toLowerCase()) > -1
        );
      });
    } else if (this.searchQuery === "") {
      // resetting the intolarances to show all the intolarances
      this.intolerances = this.allIntolerances
    }
  }

<ion-content>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let food of foods">
    <ion-item (ionChange)="onCheckbox($event)">
      <ion-label>{{ food.name }}</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox slot="end" value="{{ food.name }}" [checked]="isFoodSelected(food.name)"> </ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <h5 *ngIf="foods.length === 0">
    Oups, no food found.
  </h5>
</ion-content>
```

And create a method `isFoodSelected` in your component as:

```
isFoodSelected(testFood) {
    const tickedFoodNames = this.tickedFoods.map(food=>food.name);
    return tickedFoodNames.includes(testFood);
  }
```

This will allow you to add a `checked` attribute to your food items that persist in the list after using the search functionality.

Solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-xgsiru

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your reply. I just tried your suggestion and it partially works. Now since the start, all the items are checked by default. But, I would like them to be unchecked by default and. only to keep the checked state after I check them. What do you think?

Comment: Sorry, but I am new to coding and I am not sure really. I think it doesn't take the condition and it automatically makes them checked. Here is my code in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-axqxgk?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot! It works but now when I select one it automatically ticks all of the items. in the list

Comment: Just saw it now, sorry, but now we get to the same problem. After we search, select food and after go back to the entire list doesn't keep the selected element ticked

Comment: Hello! There were some issues with my answer earlier. The `this.intolrances` should be assigned `this.allIntolarances` when the `searchQuery == ""` and the `.includes()` check inside the  `isFoodSelected ` should ideally check on `food` instead of `food.name`. I have updated my answer with the details.